# Starship Prompt not working properly on Kubuntu

Tags: command-line, bash, kubuntu, konsole

I'm just learning how to work with the terminal, and after watching some videos, I really liked the way the [Starship Prompt](https://starship.rs/guide/#%F0%9F%9A%80-installation) looks.

Before installing the snap, I installed the powerline and firacode fonts with `sudo apt-get install fonts-powerline` and `sudo apt install fonts-firacode` respectively. Then, I installed the snap with `sudo snap install starship`.

After that, I edited the `.bashrc` file in my home directory, adding `eval "$(starship init bash)"` at the end of it. So far so good. When I open the Konsole, it seems like the Starship Prompt is working, but it shows a strange character followed by a `0%` that looks hideous.

So, I don't know if I missed any step or if it is a specific problem with Konsole.

[Screenshot of Konsole working with Starship Prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPq7U.png)

Answer (score 2):

I had to configure Starship Prompt to manually delete the extra symbols.

On the `~/.config` directory, I created a `starship.toml` file with the following configuration:

```
# Use custom format
format = """
[](bold blue)$directory$rust$package
[❯](bold blue) """

# Wait 10 milliseconds for starship to check files under the current directory.
scan_timeout = 10

# Disable the newline at the start of the prompt
add_newline = false
```

[Screenshot of Konsole](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhelK.png)